# Django: are inclusion tags in loops causing my slow rendering?

Tags: django

Still quite new to Django and concerned I've gone about this the wrong way.

My site makes use of "trails": little widget components linking to bits of content. I have a single template which renders these trails and the template has a bunch of options (whether to show an image, how many words to show, etc). I achieved this using the following inclusion tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('reviews/review_trail.html')
def review_trail(
    review, 
    coverPosition='left', 
    showLargeHeadings=False, 
    wordsToShow=30, 
    ):
        return {
            'r' : review, 
            'coverPosition': coverPosition, 
            'scoreMode': scoreMode, 
            'showLargeHeadings': showLargeHeadings, 
            'wordsToShow': wordsToShow, 
        }
```

I use this function many times in views, usually in a loop like so:

```
{% for r in reviews %}
    {% review_trail review=r coverPosition="right" %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've found perfomance to be increasingly worse of late. I've spent a while tuning static files (caching, combining, etc) and SQL calls (indexing, profiling, etc). Looking at [profiling results](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=y3iP0cLn), most of the slowness seems to come from template rendering.

Is this kind of coding detrimental to my app's performance? I thought I was being clever by following DRY principles but perhaps I'm shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Although I haven't done any template benchmarking recently, with Django 0.97 I got an enormous (1ms versus 100ms) speedup after I switched everything to Jinja2 instead. That was a real-life website with quite a lot of load on the site. Since that point I have simply not bothered with the Django template engine anymore, also because of the lack of certain features like macros.

Comment: Interesting -- I just started looking at Jinja2 after seeing performance stats like you suggest. I couldn't get the above inclusion tags to work using its syntax, though. I found it a bit tricky to follow its documentation on converting custom template tags to a Jinja2 format (using Coffin as well) -- any tips?

Comment: Try a macro instead of an inclusion tag, I'll post an answer with an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be your `reviews/review_trail.html` file:

```
{% macro review_trail(review, coverPosition='right') %}
    {{ review }} ... other stuff to render here, like the cover position
    Our cover position is: {{ coverPosition }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Now, in your other template you simply do this:

```
{% from 'reviews/review_trail.html' import review_trail %}

{% for r in reviews %}
    {{ review_trail(review=r) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you - after an evening of replacing my nested inclusion tags with these macros performance is better (not perfect, but a decent amount faster).

One thing: I still can't find a smart way of making simple tags work in Jinja2. I have a few Python functions for calculating image ratios etc -- before I just registered these as `simple_tag`s but Jinja sees them as undefined. I take it a macro in an HTML file is the wrong place for these?

Comment: It really depends on what you're looking for, if you're simply doing some html stuff than I'd recommend using macros. Do note however that Jinja is a lot more flexible than Django is, you can just pass arguments to your functions so usually it's not really needed. But in this case I would recommend using the `register.object` method from coffin which adds that method to the global scope which makes it available for calling everywhere. Writing custom tags is something only very rarely needed in Jinja and usually not what you want anyway.